# how to pass parameters on Primefaces DataTable - Pagination buttons while they get pressed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces has nice datatable pagination which works with ajax.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf

what I would like to do is when I press the button of the navigation also to pass my own parameters to the backing Beans. how I would I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `page` event in an ajax listener for your datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="yourTable">
   <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{bean.listener(param)"/>
</p:dataTable>
```